# How to set title of the application when the app is collapsed

Tags: android, google-play, android-styles

I found an interesting thing on the Google Play App: The Title of the content is shown in the app title when the app is collapsed. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: This is the app name and / or the activities label / title, depending on your android version

Answer (score 0):

If you are with Activity set the activity title

```
   setTitle("Hello StackOverflow");
```

Or if you are with fragment with ActionBar set ActionBar title

```
   getActionBar().setTitle("Hello world App");
```

If you are with support ActionBar using support library

```
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello world App");
```

And you are on the go. keep coding.